# Can I use data types like bool to compress data while improving readability?

Tags: c++, compression, bigdata, entropy, dna-sequence

My official question will be: "Is there a clean way to use data types to "encode and compress" data rather than using messy bit masking." The hopes would be to save space in the case of compressing, and I would like to use native data types, structures, and arrays in order to improve readability over bit masking. I am proficient in bit masking from my assembly background but I am learning C++ and OOP. We can store so much information in a 32 bit register by using individual bits and I feel that I am trying to get back to that low level environment while having the readability of C++ code.

I am attempting to save some space because I am working with huge resource requirements. I am still learning more about how c++ treats the `bool` data type. I realize that memory is stored in byte chunks and not individual bits. I believe that a `bool` usually uses one byte and is masked somehow. In my head I could use 8 `bool` values in one byte.

If I malloc in C++ an array of 2 `bool` elements. Does it allocate two bytes or just one?

Example: We will use DNA as an example since it can be encoded into two bit to represent A,C,G and T. If I make a struct with an array of two `bool` called DNA_Base, then I make an array of 20 of those.

```
struct DNA_Base{  bool Bit_1;  bool Bit_2; };
DNA_Base DNA_Sequence[7] = {false};
cout << sizeof(DNA_Base)<<sizeof(DNA_Sequence)<<endl;
//Yields a 2 and a 14. 
//I would like this to say 1 and 2.
```

In my example I would also show the case where the DNA sequence can be 20 bases long which would require 40 bits to encode. GATTACA could only take up a maximum of 2 bytes? I suppose an alternative question would have been "How to make C++ do the bit masking for me in a more readable way" or should I just make my own data type and classes and implement the bit masking using classes and operator overloading.

Comment: `bool` uses a complete byte actually. You can't really address a single bit in memory, unless you use a bitwise union, or a `std::bitset`.

Comment: Look at `std::bitset` or the error named `std::vector<bool>` for ways to create pseudo-containers which store elements in partial bytes.

Comment: It may not be space optimal, but using an `enum` or `enum class :char` to represent each base is probably the most readable and efficient representation.  Bitfields should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Not fully what you want but you can use [bitfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field):

```
struct DNA_Base
{
    unsigned char Bit_1 : 1;
    unsigned char Bit_2 : 1;
};
DNA_Base DNA_Sequence[7];
```

So `sizeof(DNA_Base) == 1` and `sizeof(DNA_Sequence) == 7`

So you have to pack the *DNA_Base* to avoid to lose place with *padding*, something like:

```
struct DNA_Base_4
{
    unsigned char base1 : 2; // may have value 0 1 2 or 3
    unsigned char base2 : 2;
    unsigned char base3 : 2;
    unsigned char base4 : 2;
};
```

So `sizeof(DNA_Base_4) == 1`

`std::bitset` is an other alternative, but you have to do the interpretation job yourself.

Answer (score 0):

An array of bools will be N-elements x sizeof(bool).

If your goal is to save space in registers, don't bother, because it is actually more efficient to use a word size for the processor in question than to use a single byte, and the compiler will prefer to use a word anyway, so in a struct/class the bool will usually be expanded to a 32-bit or 64-bit native word.

Now, if you like to save room on disk, or in RAM, due to needing to store LOTS of bools, go ahead, but it isn't going to save room in all cases unless you actually pack the structure, and on some architectures packing can also have performance impact because the CPU will have to perform unaligned or byte-by-byte access.

A bitmask (or bitfield), on the other hand, is performant and efficient and as dense as possible, and uses a single bitwise operation. I would look at one of the abstract data types that provide bit fields.

The standard library has bitset  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/ which can be as long as you want.

Boost also has something I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are on a 4 bit machine, the final result will be using bit arithmetic.  Whether you do it explicitly, have the compiler do it via bit fields, or use a bit container, there will be bit manipulation.

I suggest the following:

- Use existing compression libraries.
- Use the method that is most readable or understood by people other
  than yourself.
- Use the method that is most productive (talking about development
  time).
- Use the method that you will inject the least amount of defects.

**Edit 1:**
Write each method up as a separate function.
Tell the compiler to generate the assembly language for each function.
Compare the assembly language of each function to each other.

My belief is that they will be very similar, enough that wasting time discussing them is not worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can't operate on bits directly, but you can treat the smallest unit available to you as a multiple data store, and define

```
enum class DNAx4 : uint8_t { 
   AAAA = 0x00, AAAC = 0x01, AAAG = 0x02, AAAT = 0x03,
   // .... And the rest of them
   AAAA = 0xFC, AAAC = 0xFD, AAAG = 0xFE, AAAT = 0xFF
}
```

I'd actually go further, and create a structure DNAx16 or DNAx32 to efficiently use the native word size on your machine.

You can then define functions on the data type, which will have to use the underlying bit representation, but at least it allows you to encapsulate this and build higher level operations from these primitives.